# Need help debugging, macro won't run the iterations

Tags: vba, excel, loops, iteration

Firstly apologies if this has already been addressed in earlier threads. The below macro stops at the first iteration and i can't figure out why.

Essentially, I want it to open a file if cell(x,2) is true, if false do nothing and move to next iteration.

```
Sub Stack_Daily()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 6 To 12

If Cells(x, 2).Value = True Then

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Cells(x, 6).Value

End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: When it gets to the End If it gives an error msg "can't execute the code in break mode"

Answer (score 1):

Your Macro does go through all the iterations.

This runs as expected:

```
Sub Stack_Daily()
  Dim x As Integer
  For x = 6 To 12
      Debug.Print Cells(x, 2).Value
      If Cells(x, 2).Value = True Then
          Debug.Print "Cell(" & x & ", 2)" & "=" & Cells(x, 6).Value
      End If
  Next x
End Sub
```

Your issue lies elsewhere. (In your data probably)